# Dynamically Generate Class Name and CSS Attributes in Sass

Tags: css, sass, iterator, dynamically-generated, rscss

I want to dynamically generate very specific class names and attributes with an iterator and conditional checker in SCSS Sass Version 3.

If divisible by half, add half at end.
If .25 suffix only, suffix with '1q'
If .75 suffix, suffix with '3q'

Example:

```
// margin classes
// classes m-a-0 to m-a-5, 1/4 rems specified by 1q, half, 3q   
// // m-a-1q is 1/4 rem, m-a-1-1q is i.25rem

.m- {
   &a-0 {
       margin: 1rem * 0;
   }
   &a-1q {
       margin: 1rem * 0.25;
   }
   &a-half {
       margin: 1rem * 0.5;
   }
   &a-3q {
       margin: 1rem * 0.75;
   }
   &a-1 {
       margin: 1rem * 1;
   }
   &a-1-1q {
       margin: 1rem;
   }
   &a-1half {
       margin: 1rem * 1.5;
   } 
   &a-1-3q {
       margin: 1rem * 1.75;
   }
   &a-2 {
       margin: 1rem * 2;
   }
   &a-2-1q {
       margin: 1rem * 2.25;
   }
   &a-2half {
       margin: 1rem * 2.5;
   }
   &a-2-3q {
       margin: 1rem * 2.75;
   }
}
```

Should generate:

```
.m-a-0{margin:0rem}.m-a-1q{margin:0.25rem}.m-a-half{margin:0.5rem}.m-a-3q{margin:0.75rem}.m-a-1{margin:1rem} ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'll allow a slight change in naming you could do:

```
$count: 2;  
@for $i from 0 through $count * 4 {
  .m-a-#{ floor($i / 4) }#{ nth(null -1q -half -3q, $i % 4 + 1) } { 
    margin: $i / 4 * 1rem; 
  }
}

//  output
.m-a-0      { margin: 0rem;    }  
.m-a-0-1q   { margin: 0.25rem; }
.m-a-0-half { margin: 0.5rem;  }
.m-a-0-3q   { margin: 0.75rem; }
.m-a-1      { margin: 1rem;    }
.m-a-1-1q   { margin: 1.25rem; }
.m-a-1-half { margin: 1.5rem;  }
.m-a-1-3q   { margin: 1.75rem; }
.m-a-2      { margin: 2rem;    }
```